# Page not rendering; When passing props to children using protected routes in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create protected routes with react-router-dom.

Strangely the error is saying:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.

And this is the stack trace—what's strange is the error about expecting a string? Aren't I passing `"/profile"` in `history.push`??

[image: outer]

The reason I said that's strange is because in the console from dev-tools I am getting this:

```
index.js:1 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Connect(withRouter(LinkNavWithLayout)) />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
    in Route (created by PrivateRoute)
    in PrivateRoute (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in App (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(App) (created by Connect(withRouter(App)))
    in Connect(withRouter(App)) (created by MyApp)
    in Container (created by MyApp)
    in PersistGate (created by MyApp)
    in Provider (created by MyApp)
    in MyApp (created by AppWithReactRouter)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by AppWithReactRouter)
    in AppWithReactRouter (created by AppWithRedux)
    in AppWithRedux
    in Suspense (created by AppContainer)
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

To me that makes more sense as I feel the problem is in the Protected route component i.e. meaning the logic in my protected routes function or the way I am using it...

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, children, ...rest }) => (
   <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    console.log("In PrivateRoute isLoggedIn ", isLoggedIn);
    return isLoggedIn === true
    ? <Component {...props} >{children}</Component>
    : <Redirect to='/' />
   }} />
  )
```

And this is how I am using it.

```
return (
    <>
    <Switch>
     <Route
      path='/'
      exact
      render={(props) => <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}><Index {...props} /></LinkNavWithLayout>} />

     <Route
      path='/login'
      render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
     />

     <Route
      path='/register'
      render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
     />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/profile'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={
       <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Profile /></LinkNavWithLayout>
      }
     />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/dashboard'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={
       <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>
      }
     />
     {/* <Route component={()=> <h1>Not found</h1>} /> */}
    </Switch>
    </>
  )
 }
```

So why is my page not rendering at all and what do the two errors have to do with one another? Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I added *fosso's* suggestion...

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
   <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    console.log("In PrivateRoute isLoggedIn ", isLoggedIn);
    return isLoggedIn === true
     ? { component }
     : <Redirect to='/' />
   }} />
  )

  return (
    <>
    <Switch>
     <Route
      path='/'
      exact
      render={(props) => <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}><Index {...props} /></LinkNavWithLayout>} />

     <Route
      path='/login'
      render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
     />

     <Route
      path='/register'
      render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
     />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/profile'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={({ children }) => ( // not sure where you're planning on passing `children` from `PrivateRoute`
       <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Profile /></LinkNavWithLayout>
      )}
     />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/dashboard'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={({children}) => ( // not sure where you're planning on passing `children` from `PrivateRoute`
       <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>
      )}
   />
     {/* <Route component={()=> <h1>Not found</h1>} /> */}
    </Switch>
    </>
  )
 }
}
```

But now getting the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {component}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Route (created by PrivateRoute)
    in PrivateRoute (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in App (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(App) (created by Connect(withRouter(App)))
    in Connect(withRouter(App)) (created by MyApp)
    in Container (created by MyApp)
    in PersistGate (created by MyApp)
    in Provider (created by MyApp)
    in MyApp (created by AppWithReactRouter)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by AppWithReactRouter)
    in AppWithReactRouter (created by AppWithRedux)
    in AppWithRedux
    in Suspense (created by AppContainer)
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
▶ 30 stack frames were collapsed.
callback
```

And still pointing to...

[image]

Comment: What are the opening `<>` and closing `</>` doing in your return? What class is that in?

Comment: @sallf That is a short hand for a React.Fragment. So you don’t have to have non semantic <div> everywhere..However I think it renders to a <div> anyway LOL

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues.

`component` needs to be a function, in your case you're passing a React element.

In your case, this might work:

```
<PrivateRoute
   path='/dashboard'
   isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
   component={({children}) => ( // not sure where you're planning on passing `children` from `PrivateRoute`
    <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>
   )}
/>
```

As an alternative, you have to change the `PrivateRoute` component

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
 <Route {...rest} render={props => {
  console.log("In PrivateRoute isLoggedIn ", isLoggedIn);
  return isLoggedIn === true
  ? {component}
  : <Redirect to='/' />
 }} />
  )
```

But you really should have it as a separate component.

In the second example, you would be instantiating the JSX from the parent, which might not be ideal.
In the first case, `component` is generated at each re-render, which might not be necessary.

EDIT: full example

```
const {
  HashRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} = ReactRouterDOM

const Page2 = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Page2</h1>
  </div>
)

const Page1 = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Page1</h1>
  </div>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
)

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest}) => (<Route {...rest} render={props => isLoggedIn ? <Component /> : <div>Not logged in</div>} />)

const Content = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <PrivateRoute path='/page1' isLoggedIn component={Page1}/>
      <PrivateRoute path='/page2' isLoggedIn={false} component={Page2}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

const Nav = () => (
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/page1'>Page 1 (logged in)</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/page2'>Page 2 (not logged in)</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
)

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Nav />
    <Content />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Tested in a codepen. Sorry, but if there are more errors I don't think I have enough information to debug further. I'd recommend posting another question with a full example.

Comment: It appears though your suggestion created a different error!

Comment: Sorry if my comment was confusing, but I outlined 2 different solutions, no need to change both components.

Either change the `PrivateRoute` or the `Router` hierarchy.